# how can ı make a list consist of integers from given list

Tags: python

```
def int(x):
    a=[]
    for i in x:
        if type(i)==int:
            a.append(i)
    return a
```

I tried to make a list consist of integers from given list but output is `[]`.
What is wrong?
What ı want to do:

```
 input=[1,2,3,"a"]
 output=[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this filtering using `isinstance` in a list comprehension

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,"a"]
>>> [i for i in data if isinstance(i, int)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

As a side note do not shadow the name `int` with your function name, nor the function name `input` with your variable name.